# Angular/Material - Style mat-hint for big chunks of text

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular9

I'm working in an Angular 9 project, using Material.

I have a demo example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-hint-styling-issue?file=src/app/app.component.html

I'm using inputs with mat-hints. Usually the mat-hint will contain small bits of text, but there's the possibility that the text will be very large. I want to style the mat-hint to be more responsive if this happens.

Ideally, I would want the mat-hint to show all of the text, however right now it's overflowing on top of the next input. Like this:
[image]
Instead, I want it to push the next input down as much as needed to display all its text. I tried making the display a block, but didn't help.

It's also important that the other mat-hint ("Required!") be unaffected.

If the above isn't possible (to do without affecting "Required!" or a large amount of scss), then I could settle for having a max-height on the mat-hint, and controlling the over-flow text with ellipsis. However when I add a max-height, the text is cut-off, but doesn't end with ellipsis (even after having: `text-overflow: ellipsis`).

Any styling advice to get this to be more responsive?
Thank you for any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

So i was also running against the problem where my mat-hint would be cut off after two lines. But overwriting the **MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS** seems to be my fix.
Adding the provider and setting the **subscriptSizing** to **dynamic** will no longer cut off any text.

```
{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { subscriptSizing: 'dynamic' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring `mat-hint` block back to document flow by replacing `position: absolute` with `position: static`:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-hint-styling-issue-u9apte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)**

Comment: Thank you! That does let me have all the text displayed correctly :), but ideally I don't want the text to be inside the border of the input.

Comment: In this case you can put mat-hint outside of mat-form-field https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-hint-styling-issue-hg5caq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes, that does keep the text outside the border box! :)

Comment: But I think it doesn't look like hint It looks like a separate div. And I don't think displaying 
 too long hint is nice idea. Display small and if user wants to ready full the can hover and read.

Comment: @VivekJain You're absolutely correct here. But how to display - all or cutted version - is usually decided by client

Comment: True. I am not against your answer, I am just saying for UX/UI perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below css.

```
mat-hint {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

See the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-hint-styling-issue-xtdxxp)

Comment: @ineedtoknow please accept the answer if it helps to you..

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: better to use the subscriptSizing parameter and set it to dynamic. see Jeroen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your global styles if your using **sass**

```scss
.mat-mdc-form-field {
  .mat-mdc-form-field-hint-wrapper {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

**or this if your plain css**

```css
.mat-mdc-form-field .mat-mdc-form-field-hint-wrapper {
    position: static !important; 
}
```